# Jsoup Doc.select() returns null

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I fetch HTML page source from Url and save it in Jsoup Document. And I want to search a keyword in the document but it returns null. How can I fix it or any alternative solution for searching keyword in the Jsoup Document?

I tried using

```
Element element = doc.select(":containsOwn(keyword)").first();
```

But not works.
And I thought 'doc' was empty but no. I pasted it to logcat and it is not empty.

That is my code:

```
public void onGetStringData(Document doc) {

    Element element = doc.select(":contains(keyword)").first();

    Log.e(TAG, "onGetStringData: " + element.html());
}
```

That is the HTML source:In this source, I want to find '3099.00'

```
<div class="priceDetail">
            <del class="oldPrice hidden"></del>

    <div class="newPrice">
                    <ins content="3099.00">3.099,00 <span content="TRY">TL</span></ins><span class="kdv">KDV <br>DAHİL</span>
                    </div>


    <input type="hidden" id="productRealPrice" value="3099" />
    <input type="hidden" id="productDisplayPrice" value="3099" />
    <input type="hidden" id="productPrice" value="3.099" />
    <input type="hidden" id="productSDDPriceDiscount" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" id="lastModifiedDate" value="2019-07-12 07:46:43" />
</div>
```

Comment: @SamuelPhilipp HTML code is changeable. I am parsing any HTML page. And I want to search for different keywords in each one.

Comment: The keyword `3099.00` is only present in the `content` attribute not in the own text. check either the attributes or use `:containsOwn(3.099,00)`.

Comment: Print the source you get to `doc` to the console or to a file and check if it contains the values you're looking for. If it's not there - add the `userAgent` string of your browser to the request you make.